# Adding Comma in Specific Spaces using Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to add comma only at **first** and **third** spaces between 4 separated strings. I am using following regex but this is adding the `,` after each strings

```
<?php

$date = "Thursday November 3 2016";
$fdate = implode(", ", preg_split("/[\s]+/", $date));

echo $fdate;
?>
```

output:

> Thursday, November, 3, 2016

which I need to get

> Thursday, November 3, 2016

Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be over-complicating things using a regex - how about using `strtotime`??

```
$date = "Thursday November 3 2016";
echo date('l, F j, Y',strtotime( $date ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = "Thursday November 3 2016";

$dateFormat = new DateTime($date);
echo date_format($dateFormat, 'l, F j, Y');
```

Comment: Please explain your code to help others understand and make your answer more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Not that regex is the correct tool, but this is how I would have used regex for this problem:

```
$fdate = preg_replace("/(\w+) (\w+) (\d+) (\d+)/", "$1, $2 $3, $4", $date);
```